# Make methods available everywhere

Tags: c, function

I am trying to write a recursive descent parser in C and have the following problem with the availability of my methods, since C uses a top down compiler:

```
void a(){
    b();
}
void b(){
    c();
}
void c(){
    a();
}
```

How can I work around this problem so I can call all methods where I need them? I could not come up with an elegant solution, since I am rather new to C.

Comment: add to the top: `void b();` and now you can use it everywhere; likewise for any other forward declaration needed.

Comment: @SteveFriedl, when writing a prototype/forward declaration, that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens,  Then the compiler will produce code that expects no parameters.  Without the `void` the compiler will produce code that can take any number of parameter (including none)

Comment: @user3629249 - When the OP is unsure of even how to use forward declarations, I didn't feel like a brief comment that solved the immediate problem was the place to delve into the finer points as you have suggested. The accepted answer did a fine job elaborating on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally solved with function prototypes:

```
void a(void);
void b(void);
void c(void);
//^function prototypes

void a(void){
    b();
}
void b(void){
    c();
}
void c(void){
    a();
}
```

You could also use old-style declarations (without the `void` in the parens)
which would declare the functions as taking an unspecified number of promoted arguments, but those are deprecated and they result in weak typechecking and slightly worse codegen, so better put the `void` in there if the function takes no arguments.

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Thank you! Will accept as soon as I can!